# How to get shipping costs of an order with Amazon MWS Api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I would like to get shipping costs of an order.

I can get amount, customer information, purchase date of an order... but where is the shipping cost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the [Orders API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html?ie=UTF8&section=orders&group=orders&version=latest), the shipping charges for each item are stored in the `shippingPrice` property of the `OrderItem` type. You need to use the `ListOrderItems` operation to retrieve the order's items.

See page 26 of the [Orders API documentation](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/orders/MWSOrdersApiReference._V136624229_.pdf) for a description of `shippingPrice` property. See page 25 for a description of the `ListOrderItems` operation.

Comment: So there's no way to retrieve the total shipping costs of an order? You need to iterate through the orderItems and sum the sippingPrice of each item?